# Open Sans font in mac os x

Tags: macos, fonts

Is the "Open Sans" font included by default in mac os x?

I tried to search "Open Sans" by pressing `CMD + F` with the filter `system files included`
but I cannot find it, and also in the font book I have not the "Open Sans" font...

But if I go to the chrome or firefox default font settings, I can choose "Open Sans" from the dropdown...

So how this is possible?

How can I find that font in the system and remove it, and reinstall later if I will need it again?

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

1. Go to The [Google Fonts Page](http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans).
2. Open Sans will be added to your fonts collection.
3. Then click download icon and you'll have a `.zip` file option with all of Open Sans variations in it.

You can them install them using fontbook.

Comment: If Office apps were already open, quit them before continuing.

Comment: this isn't working for me, any alternate solutions ?

Comment: You are awesome man ! you saved my life